# Why is the table alias converted to lower case in this query expression

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This query shall get all products with a price reduction exceeding 30%:

```
return $query->where([
    'Products.reduced_price / Products.price <' => 0.7,
]);
```

This query results in the following error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.price' in 'where clause'
```

Why is the table alias converted to lower case? This error seems to depend on your mysql-settings. Some setups seem to be case-insensitive (for instance my dev-machine) others like my production server are case-sensitive ;)

Unfortunately it is not possible to leave out the table-alias "Products" in this condition, because there is a joined table that has also a column named "price". Leaving the alias out would lead to this error: `Column 'price' in where clause is ambiguous`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the `_parseCondition` method of `QueryExpression` class. It will assume everything after the first space to be the operator and use `strtolower` on it, thus making the alias lower-case.

This can be easily mitigated by removing all spaces from the expression like this:

```
return $query->where([
    'Products.reduced_price/Products.price <' => 0.7,
]);
```